# What is the Raphael.transformPath analogue in svg.js?

Tags: raphael, svg.js

Raphael has a nifty function to transform one path to another:

```
 R.transformPath = function (path, transform) {
   return mapPath(path, toMatrix(path, transform));
 }
```

Is there a similar function in svg.js?

Comment: I wrote code for this at some point but its not in the core. What you would do is, pull the PathArray from the path and transform every point

Answer (score 0):

To transform the path array you would do something along those lines:

```js
const arr = path.array()

arr.map(segment => {
  // ... add code to get the x and y of all the points used
  // for a line it would be segment[1] and segment[2]

  const {x, y} = new SVG.Point(segment[1], segment[2]).transform(transform)
  return [segment[0], x, y]
})
```